# (MVC) HTML Agility Pack Data Scraper Auto Updater

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, html-agility-pack

I have been trying out some data scraping using HTML Agility Pack and have sucessfully scraped a clock from a website. I'm using Visual Studios 2015 with C# MVC5.
This is the relevant content from the controller:

```
public ActionResult Clock()
{
    var html = new HtmlDocument();
    html.LoadHtml(new      WebClient().DownloadString
    ("http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/sweden/stockholm"));
    var root = html.DocumentNode;

    var p = root.Descendants()
        .Where(n => n.GetAttributeValue("id", "").Equals("ct"))
        .FirstOrDefault();

    var content = p.InnerText;
    //var points = Regex.Match(content, @"\d+").Value;
    var hurra = Regex.Replace(content, "Â", "").Trim();
    ViewData["Time"] = hurra;

    return View();
}
```

So my question is: How do I make the clock "live"? So it updates itself for example every second.

All answers and comments are welcome.

Comment: You could call the content that fetches the time ,in your Clock() after every second?

Comment: Okay, and how would I do that?

Comment: Use a timer or something.

Comment: So should I use a script in the html to call for the controller script every second?

Comment: You could do it by script or by https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx